# Do a function on click in component

Tags: blazor, razor-components

I have a button :

```
<BSButton Color="Color.Info" @onclick="LoadCategoryDetailsModal">
     <i class="fal fa-plus-circle mr-1"></i>Add New Category
</BSButton>
```

I have a component :

```
<CategoryDetails CategoryDetailModalTitle="@categoryDetailModalTitle">
</CategoryDetails>
```

In the component, I have a function to toggle the modal (show/hide); the modal is hidden by default

```
@using BlazingShop.Services
@inject ICategoryService CategoryService

<BSModal @ref="CategoryDetailsModal" IsCentered="true">
    <BSModalHeader OnClick="@OnToggle">@CategoryDetailModalTitle</BSModalHeader>
    <BSModalBody><p>Modal body text goes here.</p></BSModalBody>
    <BSModalFooter>
        <BSButton Color="Color.Primary">Save Changes</BSButton>
        <BSButton Color="Color.Secondary" @onclick="@OnToggle">Close</BSButton>
    </BSModalFooter>
</BSModal>

@code {

    BSModal CategoryDetailsModal;

    [Parameter]
    public string CategoryDetailModalTitle { get; set; }

    void OnToggle(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        CategoryDetailsModal.Toggle();
    }
}
```

I try to toggle the modal from the parent component.

Can you help me please ?

When I click on this button (in parent component):

```
<BSButton Color="Color.Info" @onclick="LoadCategoryDetailsModal">
    <i class="fal fa-plus-circle mr-1"></i>Add New Category
</BSButton>
```

I want to to this function inside the child component:

```
CategoryDetailsModal.Toggle();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I just find the answer !
Add the @ref="Modal" in your Component :

```
<CategoryDetails CategoryDetailModalTitle="@categoryDetailModalTitle" @ref="@Modal"></CategoryDetails>
```

in @Code section :

```
private CategoryDetails Modal { get; set; }
```

In the method when you click on the button :

```
 private void LoadCategoryDetailsModal()
    {
        category = new Category();
        categoryDetailModalTitle = "Add New Category";
        Modal.Toggle();
    }
```

Toggle it's a method I made in the Child component :

```
public void Toggle()
    {
        CategoryDetailsModal.Toggle();
    }
```

Comment: So what's the difference between my answer and your answer, except the vague naming changes you've made ?

Comment: No difference I post the answer in the same time as you do.

Answer (score 1):

If in your parent component you have a child component:

```
<CategoryDetails CategoryDetailModalTitle="@categoryDetailModalTitle"></CategoryDetails>
```

And a button:

```
<BSButton Color="Color.Info" @onclick="LoadCategoryDetailsModal"><i class="fal fa-plus-circle mr-1"></i>Add New Category</BSButton>
```

Then, you can define a method named LoadCategoryDetailsModal which is executed when the user clicked the above button... The LoadCategoryDetailsModal method, I guess, should contains the code that is supposed to toggle the Model window... You can do something like this:

```
private void LoadCategoryDetailsModal()
{
   CategoryDetailsModalRef.Toggle();
}
```

CategoryDetailsModalRef is an object that holds a reference to the 
CategoryDetails child component. This is how you add the @ref attribute to 
capture a reference to the CategoryDetails component:

```
<CategoryDetails @ref="CategoryDetailsModalRef" CategoryDetailModalTitle="@categoryDetailModalTitle"></CategoryDetails>
```

And in the @code block you define: `CategoryDetails CategoryDetailsModalRef;`

Note that the code above assume that you've defined a method named Toggle() in 
the CategoryDetails component whose role is to toggle the display of the modal window, perhaps by changing a boolean variable from true to false and vice versa.

Hope this helps...